main does not compile when creating a class object
I recently started C++ and it has been fun, but now I'm stuck trying to test inheritance classes (and classes in general). When you create a class, the more organized way to do it (as far as I've been told) should be to have a header file for structure and a .cpp for implementation, then you would #include "header.h" and use it on the main. But so far, I've had to put all my implementation IN my header file, cause otherwise it won't compile, and I'm not sure why. I've been circumventing the problem that way but the fact that I can't doit the proper way has been eating at me.
So for example, here are my main and my two header files. I know there is no implementation error in my .cpp files, I think I might have built something wrong but the issue only arises when I define things through multiple files.
main:
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "driver.h"

int main(){
    driver Jen;
}

driver.h:
#ifndef DRIVER_H
#define DRIVER_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "person.h"

class driver : person{

private:
    int num{0};
    int pts{0};

public:
    driver();
    driver(std::string nom, int num, int pts);
    ~driver();

    //friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const driver& driver);

    int get_num();
    int get_pts();

    void set_num(int num);
    void set_pts(int pts);

    void Display();
};

#endif // DRIVER_H

person.h:
#ifndef PERSON_H // Guard that guards against multiple inclussion
#define PERSON_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class person{

private:
    std::string nom{"Waiting for name"};
    std::string job{"Waiting for job"};

public:
    person()=default;
    person(std::string nom,std::string job);
    ~person()=default;
    
    std::string get_nom();
    std::string get_job();

    void set_nom(std::string nom);
    void set_job(std::string job);

    void Display();
};

#endif // PERSON_H

Btw, here is the error:
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccVqvx72.o: in function `main':
c:/Users/User/Documents/Prog/C++Course/9.1_InheritDeets/main.cpp:9:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `driver::driver()'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/User/Documents/Prog/C++Course/9.1_InheritDeets/main.cpp:11:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `driver::~driver()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

*  The terminal process "C:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-g3', 'c:\Users\User\Documents\Prog\C++Course\9.1_InheritDeets\main.cpp', '-o', 'c:\Users\User\Documents\Prog\C++Course\9.1_InheritDeets\output\main.exe'" terminated with exit code: 1. 


It's the linker that's failing because you haven't provided definitions of your various driver::... functions.

Failure to link against appropriate libraries/object files or compile implementation files

The error above says undefined reference to driver::driver. Looking at your code can you point to the implementation of this function? Because it is not in the code you have posted. Now you say that you have cpp files (plural) but if so you have only posted one of them. I would guess that your error also has the same cause, you have only compiled one of your cpp files. If you have two cpp files you need to compile both of them, otherwise you get the kind of errors that you have been getting.

@john The implementation for driver::driver is in the driver.cpp, I didn't post it because I thought it would be too much text, same thing for my person.cpp. I only posted the main.cpp. But I do think it might be that I'm not compiling my other .cpp (person & driver) I just don't know how.

@AlexJB That depends on how you are building your code (which I don't think you say). But it's pretty simple, however it is that you are telling it to compile main.cpp also include driver.cpp and person.cpp in that command (or configuration, or setting, or whatever).

@john Technically, I've been building it through the Build Task in New terminal with g++, then at some point I've tried implementing my own json, and then I gave up and tried with the play button on vscode. I'm not sure what it is that I'm not doing, so my files aren't linking. Thing is, it works when the implementation is in the header file, it doesn't when I put it in a .cpp, and like you said, is probably cause it's not compiling them. Cause I'm supposed to get a main.exe, driver.exe and person.exe files, and it doesn't do it.

@AlexJB OK, firstly you have to know which plugin you are using in VSCode, there are several different plugins and what you should do depends on which you have installed. Secondly even though you have three cpp files you will still only get one exe file (which might be called anything).

@AlexJB If you are using the Microsoft C/C++ plugin (this is the most common case) then you need to edit the tasks.json file so that it compiles all your cpp files.

@I'm ussing C/C++ IntelliSense, does that change something?

@AlexJB No, intellisense is just an aid to editting your code, it has nothing to do with compiling your code.

@AlexJB The microsoft plugin is just called C/C++ but the description says C/C++ intellisense, debugging and code browsing. It that what you see?

@john Yes, it's exactly that

@john Hi, so I fixed it! I'm using my task.json own builder with gcc, it does indeed only give me one file, and I'm very happy about it! Just wanted to say thank you cause talking to you helped me see through the problem and persevere.

Visual Studio Code is a popular programmer-oriented text editor.  The VIsual Studio Community 2022 is much more suitable for beginners, as it is an integrated development environment.
